# How to get the last file content generated in "Get file content using path" Power automate

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, power-automate, powerapps

I'm making an application to populate a Word document, I found a method to do this by taking an item from a SharePoint library. I would like it to take, instead of a specific image, the last image sent there.

[image]

After "/Teste Laudos/_______" there is a JPG image, I would like it to be the last one sent to the library, and not this specific one.

Comment: As far as I know, I'm afraid this is not automatically recognized to get the last file, we need to specify the path manually.

Comment: Using this method I really couldn't get very far, but now I did it another way and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem, maybe you can post your solution here to help those who have the same problem as you. Thank you for your dedication.

Comment: I would say that should be possible. Couldn't you use a Get files (properties only) action and sort this ascending and filter for jpgs in the filter query field? In a Get file content action you could use the identifier of the first file found in the outputs of that Get files (properties only) action.